# Export users from db

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, joomla2.5

What data base tables do I need to copy to transfer all users from one 2.5 site to another? I only need the users and not other tables so a complete db transfer is not applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These four table 5 tables are used to save user data.

```
#__usergroups
#__users
#__user_notes
#__user_profiles    
#__user_usergroup_map
```

where `#_` is your table prefix.Out of these 5 `#__users` is the most important.But groups table are also useful if you have custom groups associated with user.So it'll depend that what data do you need.Look at fields of these tables and figure out what tables are enough.